# How to pass RUST_BACKTRACE=1 when running a Rust binary installed in Debian?

Tags: rust, debian, environment-variables, rust-cargo, backtrace

When I run a binary using cargo, I have the option to run it as follows -

```
bash -c "RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run --bin my_binary"
```

This gives me a stack trace when the binary hits an error.
But when I create a Debian package for the same binary, how do I get stack traces on failure?

Is there some way to enable backtrace there too, if the source is implemented in Rust?

**Edit:**

I create a debian package for my cargo project using

```
cargo deb // Produces a my_binary.deb
```

This my_binary.deb can then be installed on a Debian machine as -

```
 dpkg -i /tmp/my_binary*.deb || true \
 && apt-get -f -y install
```

Comment: `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run --bin my_binary` in a normal shell works for me under Debian. (Your question is somewhat unclear, what do you mean by "create a debian"?)

Comment: @starblue creating a debian was indicating creating a debian package for `my_binary`. Have edited the question. Hope it better explains now.

Comment: Have you tried `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 my_binary`?

Comment: Thanks @starblue. It is a valid syntax to pass the flag like that while executing. Will see if the stacktrace gets printed on hitting an error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue (error message) on Linux Mint 19 after installation of alacritty (0.5.0-dev).

In terminal just run:

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 alacritty
```

or `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=full alacritty
```

Comment: please add some details or questions if you vote down.

Comment: is there any way to add this to the `config.toml` or `Cargo.toml` or something like that?

Answer (score 38):

Just in case someone is looking for setting environment variable from source code, here is how you do it:

```
use std::env;
fn main() {
  // this method needs to be inside main() method
  env::set_var("RUST_BACKTRACE", "1");
}
```

The benefit of this approach -- in contrast to manually setting the env variable from PowerShell-- is that you won't need to turn this variable off after you run this program. That is to say, 'RUST_BACKTRACE=1' is set only for this program, not others.